Is there a name for this formula for central trinomial powers?
I have determined (by applying the techniques found in this blog post) that if $a_n$ is determined by the $n$th coefficient of $(ax^2+bx+c)^n$, then the generating function of $a_n$ is
$$\frac1{\sqrt{(b^2-4ac)x^2-2bx+1}}.$$
In particular, if we write $A(x)$ for the generating function, then $\big(A(x)\big)^{-2}$ is a quadratic.
Since enumerative combinatorics is such a big field, and since the techniques involved are (somewhat?) well-known, one would imagine that this formula would already be published somewhere and that it would have a name. But I have no earthly idea how to search for it. So, I asked you: Does this formula have a name?

I wouldn't be shocked if it turns out Euler published this somewhere.

In fact, it's been mentioned on MSE already! For instance, here: Balanced ternary: combinatorial sum. There's a reference to a publication by Knuth but I haven't been able to trace it.

There is related information stated in Appendix A 7.56 of the second edition Concrete Mathematics by R. L. Graham, D. E. Knuth and O. Patashnik. Problem 7.56 (p. 380) is one of two research problems in section Exercises of chapter 7. The following is more or less verbatim from the book.

Problem 7.56: Prove that there is no simple closed form for the coefficient of $z^n$ in $\left(1+z+z^2\right)^n$, as a function of $n$, in some large class of simple closed forms.

Appendix A 7.56 provides the following answer:

Answer 7.56: Euler [113] showed that this number is also $[z^n]1/\sqrt{1-2z-3z^2}$, and he gave the formula $t_n=\sum_{k\geq 0}n^{\underline{2k}}/k!^2=\sum_{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{k}$. He also discovered a memorable failure of induction while examining these numbers: Although $3t_n-t_{n+1}$ is equal to $F_{n-1}(F_{n-1}+1)$ for $0\leq n\leq 8$, this empirical law mysteriously breaks down when n is 9 or more! George Andrews [12] has explained this mystery by showing that the sum $\sum_{k}[z^{n+10k}](1+z+z^2)^n$ can be expressed as a closed form in terms of Fibonacci numbers. H. S. Wilf observes that $[z^n](a+bz+cz^2)^n=[z^n]1/f(z)$ , where $f(z)=\sqrt{1-2bz+(b^2-4ac)z^2}$ (see [373, page 159]), and it follows that the coeffcients satisfy
\begin{align*}
(n+1)A_{n+1}-(2n+1)bA_n+n(b^2-4ac)A_{n-1}=0.
\end{align*}
The algorithm of Petkovšek [291] can be used to prove that this recurrence has a closed form solution as a finite sum of hypergeometric terms if and only if $abc(b^2-4ac)=0$. Therefore in particular, the middle trinomial coeffcients have no such closed form. The next step is presumably to extend this result to a larger class of closed forms (including harmonic numbers and/or Stirling numbers, for example).


[12] George E. Andrews, Euler's 'exemplum memorabile inductionis fallacis' and q-trinomial coeffcients, Journal of the American Mathematical Society 3 (1990), 653-669.

[113] L. Eulero, Observationes analyticae, Novi commentarii academiae sci- 299, 575, 636. entiarum imperialis Petropolitanae 11 (1765), 124{143. Reprinted in his Opera Omnia, series 1, volume 15, 50-69.

[291] Marko Petkovšek, Hypergeometric solutions of linear recurrences with polynomial coeffcients, Journal of Symbolic Computation 14 (1992), 243-264.

[373] Herbert S. Wilf, generatingfunctionology. Academic Press, 1990; second edition, 1994.


Note: I looked in [373] Herbert S. Wilf, generatingfunctionology, second edition, but unfortunately I could not find the cited information. I could find there some related information in chapter 5, Exercises 2 - 4. For instance exercise 4 (a):

4 (a): Define, for all $n\geq 0, \gamma_n=[x^n](1+x+x^2)^n$. Use the result of exercise 3 above to prove that for $n\geq 0$,
\begin{align*}
\gamma_n=[x^n]\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2x-3x^2}}\right\}.
\end{align*}


What's the "exercise 3 above" that's referenced in the last reference?

Found it. “If $u=u(t)$ satisfies $u=t\phi(u)$ and $n\ge0$, show that
$$[u^n]{\phi(u)}^n=[t^n]\left{\frac{tu'(t)}{u(t)}\right}=[t^n]\frac1{(1-t\phi'(u(t)))}.”$$

Thank you for you answer here. Would you mind taking a look at this related question? Limiting growth ratio of $[x^n]f(x)^n$
